# how to change the while loop condition depending on stuff?

Tags: php, loops, conditional-statements, while-loop

by this question what i mean is that if, by example, someone's username is "bob" then the while loop condition will be ($i < 10), and if the username is something else then the while loop condition will be ($i > 10)

```
if($username == "bob")
{
   //make this while loop condition: ($i < 10)
   // it means: while($i <10){ so stuff}
}
else
{
   //make the while loop condition: ($i >10)
}
```

Comment: I think this becomes a design issue.  Try using the strategy pattern (Google it) and you can have some methods on your interface direct the loop / condition.

Answer (score 4):

Make `do_stuff` a function, then this is perfectly readable (although special-casing 'bob' seems doubtable at best).

```
if($username == "bob")
{
   while($i<10) {
       do_stuff();
   }
}
else
{
   while($i>10) {
       do_stuff();
   }
}
```

Comment: and what if $username == bob  then i remove the while loop but leave the code inside. and if its else than bob, i put the while loop...

Answer (score 2):

```
while( ($username == 'bob' && $i <10 ) XOR $i > 10){}
```

---

`$username == 'bob'` will be evaluated first if it comes out to be `true` then `$i < 10` is evaluated.

`$var1 XOR $var2` is `true` only when one of `$var1, $var2` is `true` **but not both.**

But I myself will go with [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710120/how-to-change-the-while-loop-condition-depending-on-stuff/2710142#2710142).

Answer (score 0):

Try making two different while loops within the if and else blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?  You can just take a different path depending on the success or failure of the if.  If the code inside is the same, just call a method to avoid duplicating it.

```
if($username == "bob")
{
   //make this while loop condition: ($i < 10)
   // it means: while($i <10){ so stuff}
   while ($i < 10) {
       call_method();
   }
}
else
{
   while ($i > 10) {
       call_method();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep your code simple:

if($username == "bob")
{
   while ($i<10){
}

}
else
{
 while ($i>10){
}

}

There are other better ways to handle it but they may make your code difficult to understand like using eval which I dont like.